# Netflix wont work without NEW silverlight update

Tags: updates, wine, ppa, moonlight, netflix

ive looked through the answered questions here and none of the solutions work. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10, 64 bit on a System 76 lemur ultra.

netflix was working fine up until about 2 or 3 days ago, where it now prompts me to update silverlight. the title selection screen of netflix desktop comes up just fine, when launched from the terminal there are no errors.

ive tried to fix this problem by uninstalling and re installing netflix-desktop using the "sudo apt-get --purge remove netflix-desktop"

ive tried uninstalling netflix-desktop with the above command and uninstalling the ehoover PPA with "sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ehoover/compholio" and then reinstalling them both according to the guide you can find just about anywhere

ive tried installing the silverlight .exe and running it, it is also not effectual.

in searching i HAVE found this proposed solution that was applied about 2 months ago...

> "The new version of Netflix Desktop moves the profile location from
>   ~/.netflix-desktop to ~/.wine-browser. You might try renaming/deleting
>   the ~/.wine-browser folder and relaunching netflix-desktop (or
>   redbox-desktop) so that it creates a new profile."

but i have **NO IDEA** how to find/rename/remove the ~/.wine-browser folder...

***if nothing else, how do i find and rename/remove that folder so i can try relaunching netfix desktop?***

otherwise, are there any other work arounds to get netflix running? or is there somewhere i can find an updated PPA? i'm pretty sure all my stuff is up to date, but am willing to run whatever tests anyone recommends to verify this. a lot of people are having this problem so i dont think its a bug, and its happening very recently, so i dont think its the same problem as last february, though im hoping it has the same solution.

thanks for your time, and hopefully, your answers